# What are possible solution for periodic folder sync between machines on linux?

Tags: synchronization, remote-server

I have 2 machines, one is my computer that I coding and one is the remote machine that I run the codes. I want to code on my machine and sync the code as I save it to the remote machine. I know I can use ssh for that purpose in action but I want to work on the hardrive of my machine since it is faster. Is there any solution to sync my local copy to remote copy periodically? NON-DROPBOX

Answer (score 2):

The standard tool is `rsync`:

```
rsync -r<various other options - check man for which you need> . sshuser@host:/remote/dir
```

For development purposes however it is much [easier](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) to just use `git` (you use vcs, don't you?). The setup is somehow complicated but the advantage is that you can do it manually by git push AND only your changes (diff) is sent while rsync checks each file separatly:

1. Create a bare repository on test machine (machine you run code on)
2. Add a `post-receive` hook as describe [here](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) to it
3. Profit (simply git push when you want to sync)

The disadvantage of `git` is that it is not suitable for the large and/or binary files such as images (well [pure](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/git-bigfiles) [git](http://git-annex.branchable.com/)).

---

Both solutions don't sync automatically. My believe is that it's a feature as you usually want to exactly know what you are running and either sync now ('this is critical security fix') or only when you do something - even with testing you don't want to sync when you are in middle of writing a function.

If you do want to do it you can always add a cron entry to do it.

Answer (score 1):

rsnapshot ([here](http://rsnapshot.org)) or git-annex ([here](http://git-annex.branchable.com/)) would both cover your needs. rsnapshot is perhaps simpler (basically a wrapper around cron + rsync + ssh). git-annex is a little more complicated, but with the assistant it allows you a dropbox-like experience contained within your own servers.